Is joint normal distribution flexible in correlation?
Suppose random variables $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ follow joint normal distribution.
Conditional on $X$, we can calculate the correlation coefficient of $Y$ and $Z$. Is it always the case that this coefficient does not vary with the value of $X$?

Yes, this is the case. We have the following covariance matrix for the joint Gaussian:
$$
\Sigma = \Sigma^{T} = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_{XX} & \sigma_{XY} & \sigma_{XZ}\\
                         \sigma_{YX} & \sigma_{YY} & \sigma_{YZ}\\
                         \sigma_{ZX} & \sigma_{ZY} & \sigma_{ZZ}
         \end{bmatrix}
$$
And we have correlation coefficient equivalent to $\frac{\sigma_{YZ}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{YY}}\sqrt{\sigma_{ZZ}}}$. Notice that all the variables here are independent from $X$ because these values are constants that are available in the covariance matrix. Remember that a jointly gaussian random variable is a linear combination of Gaussian random variables and Gaussian is fully parameterized by its covariance and mean.
